Open .ui File in CLion - Temporarily Ignore File Association
I am using CLion for Qt development on an Ubuntu 24.04 machine. I have associated .ui files with QT Designer, and I use that most of the time when building UIs so that's the way I would like to keep it.
But I occasionally have a need to edit the xml of the .ui files. Currently I do this by opening it in nano and editing, but I'm wondering if there is a way to open the xml file in CLion?
So, is there a way to open the .ui files in CLion, without changing the file associations? For example a menu item somewhere that says "Open With CLion" or similar thingy? (I couldn't find one so far though).
I have looked at issues here at SO and Jetbrain's YouTrack, but all of them seem to be about changing file association, or file associations not working etc. I haven't found any guidance about how to open a .ui file in CLion, while still preserving the file association for Designer.
Hope the question is clear enough :)

This seems more a question for https://askubuntu.com or https://superuser.stackexchange.com.


I achieve this by using the IdeaVim plugin, via the command :e xxx.ui.
This can only be considered a tricky way to get the job done, and I don't know if there are any other ideas for a solution.
If you don't know Vim, I suggest you learn it.


Install IdeaVim plugin in CLion.
Enter normal mode (which is an editing mode unique to vim), the cursor display resembles a square instead of a vertical line.
Type ":" to enter command mode (also unique to Vim), then type "e xxx.ui" to open the .ui file in CLion.


The final realization is similar:

It is important to note that the following commands were added separately by me, in fact you can open any file by typing the above commands to open the .ui file.

